# Data getting added after the element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to add a partial class into a  element but it is getting added after the element.
 There is only one `divCartHeader` in the HTML.

Partial class : (pagingLinkHelperPartial.cshtml)

```
<!--START PAGINATION MENU-->
<div class="container-fluid subMenuBKG" id="paginationDiv">
    <div class="row" id="dtlRptPrvNxtLnk">

    </div>
</div>
<!--END PAGINATION MENU-->
<!--START Cart Header MENU-->
<div id="divCartHeader">
</div>
<!--END Cart Header MENU-->
```

CartHeader.cshtml

```
<div class="CartHeader"> 
    <div class="CartInfo">
    </div>
    <div class="CartButtons">
    </div>
</div>
```

Cart.js :

```
var Mod = Mod || {};
Mod.Carts = function (e) {

 if (ddlselectedVal == "ViewCart") {

  var frmViewCartValiator = $("#frmViewCart").validate({
 var url = EnvironmentURL + "Reports/Stats/GetListingsInCart" ;

    $.post(url,
             function (data) {

 var $emailForm = $("#frmPostToEmailReports");
  $emailForm.find("#IsCart").val(true);                                         

  var url = $("#applicationName").val() + "/Stats/GetCartHeader";
  if (IsCart) {
         $.post(url,
         function (data) { 
                         $("#divCartHeader").empty().replaceWith(data);
                         //$("#divCartHeader").empty().append(data);
                         //$("#divCartHeader").html(data);
                                             });
                                    };  


});
});


var postData = { AgentId: agentId, Mlsnums: SelectedMlsnums, ActionTypeValue: Action};
            var viewCartDialog = Mod.ReportsDialog({ title: 'View A Cart', close: closeViewCartDialog, open: openViewCartDialog, position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window } });
            viewCartDialog.url = EnvironmentURL + 'MLSReports/Stats/Cart'
            //viewCartDialog.url = EnvironmentURL + 'Stats/Cart'
            viewCartDialog.targetElement = '#myModalMail'
            viewCartDialog.formName = '#frmViewCart'
            viewCartDialog.postData = postData
            viewCartDialog.open();
}

}
```

[image]

As shown in this picture I am trying to add   `CartHeader.cshtml` to  `<div id=divCartHeader>` but it is getting added to after the element.

Comment: It seems you have tried `$("#divCartHeader").empty().append(data);`. What was the result ? Now you are replacing `divCartHeader` div with `data` and it seems there is a issue in your `CartHeader.cshtml`. It may contain empty `divCartHeader` div.

Comment: thank you. the result is the same. data getting added after #divCartHeader.  Yes you are right the first time divCartHeader will be empty

Comment: Does `CartHeader.cshtml` contains `divCartHeader` ?

Comment: no. divCarHeader is an element in the Layout page. I am trying to the cartHeader.cshtml into divCartHeader.

Answer (score 1):

A little confused about the question, are you trying to add the class to the div id="divCarHeader"? If so could you just use the jquery addclass method?

`$('#idOfItemYouWantToAddAClassTo').addClass("class you want to add")`?

If this is not what you are looking for - comment further to clarify my misunderstanding :)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. updated the question. I wanted to add CartHeader.cshtml not just a class

Answer (score 1):

To apply `CartHeader` and `stickyDetailReportCartHeaderCartViewNoHeader` classes to the div simply use:

```
$('#divCartHeader').addClass('CartHeader stickyDetailReportCartHeaderCartViewNoHeader');
```

**EDIT**: Ok, after the comment and the edit made to the question, I think it is a bit more clear what you want to do. So, if I understand correctly, you want to inject the contents of CartHeader.cshtml into a particular div found in the pagingLinkHelperPartial.cshtml page.

If you can access the actual markup of CartHeader.cshtml as a string then you can just do the following:

```
$('#divCartHeader').append('<div class="CartHeader"><div class="CartInfo"></div><div class="CartButtons"></div></div>');
```

Otherwise, you can use an iframe:

```
<div id="divCarHeader">
    <iframe src="CartHeader.cshtml"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. updated the question. I wanted to add CartHeader.cshtml not just a class

Comment: @BumbleBee please see whether my updated response helps